# How to make a anchor link page swipeable?

Tags: javascript, html

I am recently struggling on this problem, "how to make the anchor link swipeable".....

How can I make swipe from #page1 to #page2?

All my page's content are written in one page javascript, the structure looks like this:

```
 if (hash === "#page1") {
        ....."});


} else if (hash === "#page2") {
   .....});

} else if (hash === "#page3") {
   .....});
```

Refer the original page: http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/03/hardware-accelerated-page-transitions-for-mobile-web-apps-phonegap-apps/

My Page: http://siuyian.com/test9/

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create inside your JS code, a logic that on every swipe gesture to the right or left, you will swap the Body's class name, and this on his turn, will activate your css based transition?

For swipe gestures, exist great library name [Hammer.JS](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/)

Here is [a Carousel Demo](http://rawgithub.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/master/examples/carousel.html) that does exactly what you wanted. Thing is that you will have to manage your app display when the user will enter a hash page directly.

Question - I would recommend you to use MVC solution for your SPA (Single Page Application). It handles routing, and many other things you might need to use for your application. Give it a shot.

BTW - Your page is broken.